# Exim .forward fails unexpectedly

Tags: email, exim, mail-forwarding

I am trying to enable synchronous processing of incoming email on a host running exim. In the absence of a .forward file, mail gets appended to the expected /var/spool/mail/$USER

I added a very simple .forward file to test out the functionality:

```
| cat - >>/home/mailfiter/mailin
```

and created a file in the home directory with 0666 permissions. However when I send a message, it does not arrive in the expected location. The exim logs report:

```
2019-08-07 14:48:36 1hvMIt-0005GY-Pl ** | cat - >>/home/mailfiter/mailin
 <mailfilter@netmonitor.bip> R=userforward T=address_pipe: Child process of 
 address_pipe transport returned 1 from command: /bin/cat
```

Here, the 1 [suggests a permissions issue](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/10/linux-error-codes/) but:

- /home is drwxr-xr-x,
- /home/mailfilter is drwxrwxr-x and owned by mailfilter:mail,
- /home/mailfilter/mailin is -rw-rw-rw-

Changing the .forward to create a new file in /tmp resulted in the same error.

This is a Centos 7 box with SELinux disabled.

Comment: changing /home/mailfilter drwxrwxrwx  had no impact - still get same error. Same error with `| whoami >/tmp/receivedmail`

Comment: I always forget and can't test now;  but isn't a `.forward` one of those files where you have to add a line feed (`\n` or simply press enter) character to the last non-empty line to terminate the last command?

Comment: There is a newline at the end of the command. Very oddly, if I wrap the command in sh -c "..." (e.g. `| sh -c "whoami ./tmp/newmail"` it works as expected and the pipe is execting as the user of the receiving mailbox (WTF!?)

Comment: And hwne you use an absolute path in your commands, does that make a difference?

Comment: Yes, using absolute paths.